# Flutter build Gradle android error on Android simulator

Tags: flutter, gradle, build

I'm facing this issue. Any suggestion ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide, you gradle.setting file?

Comment: I figure out, the problem was on package google sign in. I remove it and now works correctly.